# Making UIFont Black/Heavy and Italic

Tags: swift, xcode, uifont

How can I set a font for a label **heavy** AND **italic**?

Examples from SO does not work:

```
labelCurrentDate.font = UIFont(descriptor: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .black).fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitItalic)!, size: 32)
```

Also does not work:

```
extension UIFont {
    static func systemFontItalic(size fontSize: CGFloat = 17.0, fontWeight: UIFont.Weight = .regular) -> UIFont {
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: fontWeight)
        return UIFont(descriptor: font.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitItalic)!, size: fontSize)
    }
}
```

Edit:

My "real" code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelCurrentDate: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        labelCurrentDate.font = UIFont(descriptor: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .black).fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitItalic)!, size: 32)
        labelCurrentDate.textColor = colorLightMainText
    }
}
```

My outcome:

[image]

As you can see, my label text weight is not "black" - it is a normal font weight, but I expect it to be black.

Comment: The label just has the attribute "Italic". The weight iss not "black" or "heavy".

Comment: I have made your suggested edits

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested like this:

```
let weights : [UIFont.Weight] = [
    .ultraLight, .thin, .light, .regular, 
    .medium, .semibold, .bold, .heavy, .black
]
var top : CGFloat = 25
for weight in weights {
    let desc = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32).fontDescriptor.addingAttributes([
        UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.traits: [
            UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey.weight: 
                weight.rawValue,
            UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey.symbolic: 
                UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits.traitItalic.rawValue
        ]
    ])
    let lab = UILabel()
    lab.font = UIFont(descriptor: desc, size: 0)
    lab.text = "This is a test"
    lab.sizeToFit()
    lab.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 20, y: top)
    self.view.addSubview(lab)
    top += lab.bounds.height + 8
}
```

This is what I see:

[image]

So it seems to me that we are getting all the different weights in an italic typestyle.

Comment: Thank for posting the solution. In the case, I'm using a custom font family, how can I maintain the font family without override it with the system one?.